# Spring-AOP: @AfterReturning advice confusion(s)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

```
@Pointcut("execution(* package.method(..))")
public void onComplete() {
}
```

Given above, I tried to declare an `@AfterReturning` advice in following ways:

```
//Sample 1      
@AfterReturning(value="onComplete()",
                returning="returnValue")
public void callOnCompletion(Object returnValue){               
    // aditional code here ..
}

//Sample 2
@AfterReturning(pointcut="onComplete()",
                returning="returnValue")
public void callOnCompletion(Object returnValue){               
    // aditional code here ..
}

//Sample 1 with JoinPoint
@AfterReturning(value="onComplete()",
                returning="returnValue")
public void callOnCompletion(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue){               
    // aditional code here ..
}

//Sample 2 with JoinPoint
@AfterReturning(pointcut="onComplete()",
                returning="returnValue")
public void callOnCompletion(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue){               
    // aditional code here ..
}
```

My doubts are as follows:

- What is the difference between `value` and `pointcut` attributes passed to `@AfterReturning` ?
- Which one of the two(`value` and `pointcut`), is default ?
- When to pass a `JoinPoint` parameter to the advice and when not to pass? Is there any rule  or situation ? I have seen examples which are defined with out `JoinPoint`. But when I tried to pass `JoinPoint` to `callOnCompletion(..)` method, I get `formal unbound in pointcut ...` error while initialization.
- Is parameter `returnValue` needed for `void` return type ?
- Is parameter `returnValue` mandatory for those methods which actually return a value?